# How to convert all footnotes to endnotes in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org

Could somebody advise how I can convert my footnotes in LibreOffice to endnotes?

I have a few hundred, and I want to keep my continuous numbering. In LibreOffice, I know how to convert them; butm it does not keep my numbering, and it divides the notes into several sections. I found on Google that Microsoft Office converts them, but I did not find it in Libre- or OpenOffice. Also, Microsoft Word did not do that in my 2007 version.

Comment: How did you convert the footnotes to endnotes? How does libreoffice handle the numbering currently? Do you use the "master document" feature or just one big odt file?

Answer (score 6):

Try going to Tools / Footnotes & Endnotes.  Select the Footnotes tab.  Change the selection from "end of page" to "end of document".  It changed all of mine in the whole document, just like I was hoping for.

Comment: Great answer and so simple! You wouldn't believe the crazy convoluted solutions out there!

Comment: Doesn't work if you have a combination of both endnotes and footnotes.  It creates two sets of endnotes.

Answer (score 0):

Download SoftMaker FreeOffice. Open your LibreOffice document. Click Insert > Footnote > Options. Click Position. Change as desired. Save your document. Call it up again in LibreOffice.

Comment: I do not recommend installing SoftMaker FreeOffice. On my system it prevented LibreOffice from starting even after uninstalling FreeOffice. I solved this problem by following user352036 steps and then saving the document as .docx. Close the document and open from LibreOffice. There should now be one uniform set of endnotes. Save as .odt. If necessary go to Tools > Footnotes and Endnotes and in the Endnotes tab change the number style.